# Model that can make a prediction (classification) based on a sub set of features

Tags: modeling, feature-selection

Model that can make a prediction (classification) based on a sub set of features

What is the recommended approach, best model or algorithm that handles use-case where we want to predict based on sub-set of feature ?

Example Use-case
* create a 10 feature model
* make a prediction (predict a target class) based off 5 of the 10 features

A linear classifier built on 10 features requires values for all those features when making a prediction.

If we have feature 1-5 only we would need to build a 5 feature model.

Or give real values for feature 1-5 and some dummy/median/average values for remaining features.

Creating a separate model for each combination of features does not scale (think of case where we need to model 100 features).

Is there a recommended way of achieving this goal ?

Answer (score 1):

You primarily have three options (particularly 2 & 3 are somewhat similar):

1. You can come up with a good imputation method (e.g. for continuous features after some suitable transformation look at their covariance matrix and impute on that basis) and impute the unavailable data.
2. You can train a model that implicitly handles missing values (e.g. xgboost has a default direction in each tree split, in which missing data are assigned, it may help if you have some actual missing data to make this direction be sensible).
3. You explicitly code data as missing (and possibly artificially create missingness* and then code data as such) with a code that does not coincide with any real value, e.g. -1 for strictly positive numbers. Then you use a model that can deal with non-linearities (e.g. neural networks) to reflect that such data are to be treated differently than observed data.

* This can be tricky, because your missingness process may totally mismatch what is missing in real-life. Under missing completely at random you would be fine though.

Comment: Imputation-for-prediction methods studied [here](http://clinchem.aaccjnls.org/content/55/5/994) include instant re-fits of regression models based on the "fast backwards stepdown" approximation as in the R `rms` package `fastbw` function, to get predictions using a subset of predictors.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. Re imputation, is it correct to say that from the training data we can predict what a missing value could be ? Let's say we want to make a prediction but have values for only 5 of the 10 features. We then look for a record in the training set with same/similar values (similar values to our 5 features) and look at the values of the remaining 5 features ?

Comment: It depends. If whether the value is missing depends on the missing value even for patients with otherwise similar observed values (missing not at random), it can be very difficult to do so in a good way. On the other hand, if the missing values only depend on what is observed (missing at random), then you should be fine. The big problem is that you cannot tell whether data are MNAR or MAR by looking at the non-missing data. You can speculate and make assumptions, of course.

Comment: Thanks again for the feedback. It's much appreciated. Will update with my findings.